# Reusing regex class for matching in multiple threads

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, thread-safety

Is this code considered as a thread safe in web app environment? Specifically `IsMobile` funcion?
Could it be called in high traffic web application from a controller.

I'm reading on MSDN that regex class is a thread safe, but collection returned from matches can be problematic, so I am not sure does this apply for my use case.

```
static Regex rg = new Regex(@"(?:phone|windows\s+phone|ipod|blackberry|(?:android|bb\d+|meego|silk|googlebot) .+? mobile|palm|windows\s+ce|opera\ mini|avantgo|mobilesafari|docomo|KAIOS)");
private static bool IsMobile(string agent)
{
     
    var matchedAgents = rg.Matches(agent);

    if (matchedAgents.Count > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You could just `return (matchedAgents.Count > 0);` ... Related: since you do not use any _shared_ resource outside the threadsafe regex instance: should be fine.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be thread safe? Matching doesn't mutate the Regex object, and the docs have alreadys aid it is thread safe. Why do you doubt them?

Comment: Btw: Maybe consider [`IsMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Refactored according to suggestions. Thanks all. If someone wants to writes a solution, I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @Robert I would also suggest to consider to use another ctor which receives a `RegexOptions` parameter as well: `RegexOptions.Complied`. It might be also interesting to use the `Regex.CompileToAssembly` method. [1](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/04/24/making-string-validation-faster-no-regular-expressions.html), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices#regular-expressions-compiled-to-an-assembly)